# APS: Add properties to Property Set

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am wondering if it is possible to add a property to a property set to a model stored in BIM360/ACC per API.

In my application that is using the viewer API to show a 3D model I would like to add a property to a specific property set to certain elements.

Given an element id, a property set name, a property name, and a value for that property I am looking for an endpoint with which I can set that value to that property of that element.
Preferably, I would like to call several of these requests in a batch.

I tried looking at the API specifications (like model derivative API) but could not find any endpoint that would allow this.

Answer (score 0):

While this is something that the new [AEC Data Model API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/aecdatamodel-beta/v1/developers_guide/overview/) may address in the future, I'm afraid there's currently no way for you to add custom element properties to designs in APS.

Depending on your specific use case, you could also consider storing your custom data elsewhere, and integrate it with your designs during runtime, as they're being viewed. The Viewer SDK allows you to customize the property panel and the information that it displays: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/adding-custom-properties-property-panel.